# Database Functional Dependency

Tags: relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I have the following table:

I need to identify the functional dependencies in this table. BranchID(primary key) is unique and it is the same story with Address and Phone_number. I have an idea on what is but I need to double check to see if I am correct. In needing to identify the functional dependencies, I am struggling to understand whether the Address and Phone_Number attributes are functionally dependent on BranchID seeing as the attributes themselves can uniquely identify the entire tuple.

Comment: Can one BranchID have multiple addresses or phone numbers?

Comment: No in this situation it has only one address and one phone number

Answer (score 0):

Both Address and Phone number are functionally dependent on Bramch ID.

Comment: How comes? I thought that the fact address and phone_number are unique this means that don't need branchid to be uniquely identified.

Comment: I assume that Address and Phone number are address and phone number of the branch if not then it would not be functionally dependent.